# Forecasting in sas for multiple products?

Tags: sas, forecasting

How do we forecast in sas for multiple products or sku's. For example if there are 100 products and their respective sales data in a dataset.  How do we forecast for all the 100 products without writing the code 100 times.

PS - i am very new to sas.

Comment: It depends on which SAS products you use. Just SAS Foundation, EBI stack, or even Vija?

Comment: Your most ideal solution is Forecast Server, which is designed specifically to do exactly what you are asking. If not, you'd need to do a lot of manual work designing your own ARIMA term selection algorithms, or settle with `by` groups in `proc autoreg.`

Comment: BY groups. Many procs have a BY group statement that basically says does exactly this for every group identified by the BY variables.